# puppeteer do not work in bitnami ubuntu lightsail sever

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, bitnami

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] , headless: 'new'});

'sitesmonitoring' is myapp root folder

but throw error[
Error: read ECONNRESET                                                                  x
x                                             xx sitesmonitoring >     at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {                    x
x                                             xx sitesmonitoring >   errno: -104,                                                                          x
x                                             xx sitesmonitoring >   code: 'ECONNRESET',                                                                   x
x                                             xx sitesmonitoring >   syscall: 'read'                                                                       x
x                                             xx sitesmonitoring > }                                                                                       x
x                                             xx sitesmonitoring > Error: Failed to launch the browser process!                                            x
x                                             xx sitesmonitoring > /home/bitnami/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-1108766/chrome-linux/chrome: error while    x
x                                             xx sitesmonitoring > TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting                                       x
x                                             xx sitesmonitoring >     at Interface.onClose (/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/sitesmonitoring/node_modules/@pup  x
x                                             xx sitesmonitoring >     at Interface.emit (node:events:525:35)                                              x
x                                             xx sitesmonitoring >     at Interface.close (node:internal/readline/interface:533:10)                        x
x                                             xx sitesmonitoring >     at Socket.onend (node:internal/readline/interface:259:10)                           x
x                                             xx sitesmonitoring >     at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)                                                 x
x                                             xx sitesmonitoring >     at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)                           x
x                                             xx sitesmonitoring >     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) , above code arror me
]

please give me proper solution